# Mac Keybinding in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

I am trying to set up a custom key binding in Sublime Text 2 (on Mac) so that I could use my keyboard "Home" and "End" keyboard keys to go to the beginning / end of line(s) as I am used to using those keys from PC. But I am not having much luck.

As of now, I have to user "Ctrl + e" & "Ctrl + a" in Sublime to go to the beginning or end of the line.

I was trying to edit the following file.

Default (OSX).sublime-keymap --User

I am not sure what "command" to add to my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

> [
>       { "keys": ["home"], "command": "???" },
>       { "keys": ["end"], "command": "???" } ]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also remap home and end in OS X. Save a property list like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
  "\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLine:;
  "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
  "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
}
```

Then quit and reopen Sublime Text or other applications to apply the changes.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://lri.me/keybindings.html for more information.

Comment: Hi Lauri,
Thanks for your answer. I did additional research after reading your answer and your answer does seem to be the way to go. 

However, I actually can't find "KeyBindings" folder on my system.
If it's there, i can't find it under ~/Library/.

I am using: MacBook Pro: Software  OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: @Vasek It doesn't exist by default, but you can just create it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question how to set up "Home" and "End" keyboard keybinding in Sublime Text 2 on Mac

The following code goes to Key Bindings - User file

> { "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol",
>   "extend": false} }, { "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args":
>   {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }